# VBA Delete userform control object that is off-screen

Tags: vba, userform

I added an Option Button to a userform and it has disappeared off-screen.
I know it is still there, and I can access it though code.

It's not the end of the world, but for completeness, I'd prefer to delete it. I just can't access it in the UI. Obviously, if I could click on it in the IDE Userform window, I could easily delete it.

My thought was that I could change its location :

```
Dim x As Variant

For Each x In Me.Controls
    Debug.Print x.Name
    If x.Name = "OptionButton1" Then
        Debug.Print x.Left & ", " & x.Top
        x.Left = 1
        x.Top = 1
    End If
Next x
```

This works, but only during runtime. It goes back to its original location as soon as the program ends.  FWIW, it's current location is 240, -528.

Does anyone know another way to access the object? I've also tried

```
Me.Controls.Remove "OptionButton1"
```

which also only works during runtime.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the "Properties" window (`F4`) in the top dropdown list select the `OptionButton1` then change the values in the `Left` and `Top` properties.

Comment: Thank you @simpLE MAn. I almost never use that drop down and had completely overlooked it.

Comment: @brett_x; No problem, I never use it myself ;)